# best practice for navigation design

Tags: user-interface, menu, navigation, responsive-design, jmenuitem

I got a work to recreate a website. In that website, There is a menu bar which containing 17 main menu items and their sub menu. The problem is how to design a such a large menu bar. right now its look like this[image]

I need to redesign this structure and i'am looking out for some decent way to display this links. My question is completed related to design.

Any suggestions would be a great help..

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No doubt, you should consider simplifying this menu by classifying and regrouping menu items. In this form your menu is simply not usable, so instead of trying to display this, try to simplify it first, and the solution will come naturally.

In other words - "divide to conquer".

There is always a way to classify 17 elements in not more then 5 or 6 on the top level.

A simple example - "Member ID" and "Member Search" could probably belong to a same "Member" Menu. You should also consider submenu items and not only these 17. They can probably be somehow reorganized and restructured so you have not more then 5-6 items in each group.

Answer (score 0):

17 Main menu items are a lot for navigation bar.
[look at the fullscreen nav in this website](http://www.hugeinc.com/).u can try this or have an off-canvas like [this website](http://www.awwwards.com/)